# Infer class argument type from super call

Tags: typescript, generics

In my project using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org), there is a `ClientEvents` interface that holds event argument tuple types:

```
interface ClientEvents {
  ready: [];
  warn: [reason: string]
  message: [message: Message];
  // ...some more events
}
```

I also have an `EventHandler` class, which takes a type argument:

```
abstract class EventHandler<E extends keyof ClientEvents> {

  protected constructor(public eventName: E) {}

  abstract execute(...args: ClientEvents[E]): void;
}
```

The problem is that I can't extend this class using type inference for `E`, even if it's explicitly set in the `super()` call:

```
// Error: Generic type 'EventHandler<E>' requires 1 type argument(s).
class ReadyHandler extends EventHandler {

  public constructor() {
    super('ready'); // I want to infer the type using this argument
  }

  public execute() {
    // Some more code
  }
}
```

Is there a way to infer class argument types using the arguments of a `super()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not easily; inference generally doesn't work that way.  You could, of course, write it out:

```
class ReadyHandler extends EventHandler<"ready"> {    
  public constructor() {  super('ready');  }    
  public execute() {}
}
```

If you want to avoid that redundancy you could refactor or encapsulate `EventHandler` so that you give it an actual string of type `E` and `E` will be inferred from it.  The resulting class will no longer be generic.  For example:

```
function SpecificHandler<E extends keyof ClientEvents>(eventName: E) {
  abstract class SpecificHandler extends EventHandler<E> {
    constructor() { super(eventName) };
  }
  return SpecificHandler;
}

class MessageHandler extends SpecificHandler("message") {
  public execute(msg: Message) {

  }
}
```

I'm not sure it's worth it, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-1swNa-apS7FSOMS5ysKZRFNFptEDEehlCN0RjoimLORAA)

Comment: Looks like this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you were creating an instance of a class, the generic type could be inferred from a constructor argument, but in the case of subclassing this doesn't happen with `super`. TypeScript needs the generic type to be part of the type definition when you extend the class. I'm guessing, but I think this may be because TypeScript doesn't necessarily know whether the generic type is needed before `super` gets called (if it gets called correctly at all).

You can get around this by also making the subclass generic and passing the generic type to the super class.

```
type EventKeys = keyof ClientEvents;

class ReadyHandler<E extends EventKeys> extends EventHandler<E> {
  constructor() {
    // cast is necessary or TS will complain since you could technically
    // do `new ReadyHandler<'wait'>`.
    super('ready' as E);
  }
}
```

In this case, `E` is correctly inferred from `ReadyHandler`'s constructor, so you can call `new ReadyHandler()` without specifying the type argument.

An alternative is presented in the other answer which is just to specify the type as in `EventHandler<'ready'>` which of course requires you to write `'ready'` twice. It's up to you what you think is more convenient.